# C++ overloaded operator argument evaluation order

Tags: c++

The `readByte` and `readInt` are inline methods. The problem is that the `readInt` call is actually executed first, so i get wrong OPCODE, cause it is already poped by the`readInt` call. Is it normal? I think they should be performed in order as they appear in source code.

```cpp
log << "OPCODE: " << std::hex << (unsigned int)bytes.readByte() << ", DIFF: " << bytes.readInt() << std::endl;
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with operator precedence. It's the order of evaluation of operands.

Comment: There is only one `readByte()` call here.

Comment: The `<<` operator is evaluated left-to-right. That is just how the world turns.

Comment: @chris It is about the order of evaluation of *operands.*

Comment: @EJP, My bad, I was thinking about functions (which are close enough that it's a terminology issue here).

Comment: @riodoro Not so. See the duplicate.

Comment: @riodoro1, Note that I use two different compilers here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ac6e925bab1ded6